# OrientDB 3.0.0 creating embedded give java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jdbc, orientdb

I try to create an embedded OrientDB and create some Vertex, add some properties, ... But I get Null pointer exception in the first line!

14

```
OrientDB orientdb = new OrientDB("embedded:./databases/", 
        OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
        orientdb.create("test", ODatabaseType.PLOCAL);

            try (ODatabaseSession dbSession = orientdb.open("test", "admin","admin");) {
                OClass person =  dbSession.createVertexClass("Person");
                OClass address = dbSession.createVertexClass("Address");

                person.createProperty("firstName", OType.STRING);
                person.createProperty("lastName", OType.STRING);

                dbSession.close();
            } 

            orientdb.close();
```

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.onEmbeddedFactoryInit(Orient.java:929)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.(OrientDBEmbedded.java:63)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBInternal.embedded(OrientDBInternal.java:107)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB.(OrientDB.java:164)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB.(OrientDB.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apsolutions.orientdb.example.TestOrientDB.main(TestOrientDB.java:14)

Comment: you should explain what you aspect from the above code

Comment: What do you mean by aspect? If you mean expect then the answer is:
I try to create an embedded OrientDB and create some Vertex, add some properties, ...
But I get Null pointer exception in the first line!
I appreciate your help to solve the problem.

Comment: Then write it in the question by editing it ;)

Comment: Remove the `./` in the filename and the end slash

Comment: cricket_007 thanks for reading, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have debugged the source code and found the location of the error but don't know how to solve the problem yet.
In the file Orient.java

 public void onEmbeddedFactoryInit(OrientDBEmbedded embeddedFactory) {
    OEngine memory = engines.get("memory");
    if (!memory.isRunning())
      memory.startup();
    OEngine disc = engines.get("plocal");
    if (!disc.isRunning())
      disc.startup();
    factories.add(embeddedFactory);
  }
the memory variable is null after the first line!!!

Comment: In Orient.java file, code should check for null value of variable memory before calling if(!memory.isRunning)   (lines 928, 929, ...)

Comment: My mistake, I was using the jdbc-all.jar library while, I should of used jar files from the lib folder of the orient-3.0.0 distribution.

Thanks for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake, I was using the jdbc-all.jar library while, I should of used jar files from the lib folder of the orient-3.0.0 distribution. Thanks for all who tried to help.